# Call Jquery on function when observable is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have an event on my input fields that does something everytime the value in it was changed. This works  correctly but when i want to change the values of an observable in my viewmodel with a function, the event won't be called.

I could trigger the event manually in my function but i wanted to ask if there is a better way to do this.

Part of my Code:

```
$("body").on("input", "input", function(){
    alert('changed');
    // DO SOMETHING
});

var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable();

    self.setDefaultValue = function() {
        self.firstName('');
    }
};
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/19253/

Answer (score 0):

Since your jquery event handler is a fixed constraint, you can make a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) that triggers your jquery event on update.  You can do this a few different ways, but here're a couple of approaches:

```
<input data-bind="value: firstName, trigger: {event: 'input', watch: firstName}"/>
<input data-bind="triggeringValue: firstName"/>
<input data-bind="value: firstName, triggerInput"/>
```

In the first approach, your custom binding's "update" function would fire for any change to `firstName` and you could then `$(element).trigger(valueAccessor().event)`.

In the second approach, your custom binding could extend knockout's [basic "value" binding](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/value.js) and just trigger a hard coded 'input' event.

In the third approach, you could get the value binding from the `allBindings` parameter in your update function, then bind the trigger to it.

Comment: The thing is the jquery event handler is already used by a version of an application that doesn't require knockout so this code has to be the same. I could recode all events to make them compatible but i tought there could be something to use the already written code. As i said, I can trigger the event manually but if there's a better approach I'd like to look into some details.

Comment: Agreed with the other answer, you should avoid DOM manipulation outside of knockout.  This sounds less like a technical issue and more like an organizational one.  Convince whoever is saying you shouldn't change the old code that you really should.  That said, the main problem with the existing code is that it's using the `input`event instead of `change` which I think would pick up the change from your view model.

Comment: btw, I updated the answer with what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Please avoid DOM manipulation outside of knockout.

You can do the following:

- Change your binding to inclue [`valueUpdate` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/value-binding.html)
- Use `subscribe` to be notified when your value changes

HTML:

```
 <p>First name: <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "input"' /></p>
```

JS:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable();

    self.setDefaultValue = function() {
        self.firstName('');
    }
    self.firstName.subscribe(function () { alert('changed'); });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Note that you can easily reuse the function if you do not need the context:

```
function onChanged() {
    alert('changed');
}

//...

self.firstName.subscribe(onChanged);

//some other place
$("body").on("input", "input", onChanged);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/19253/